# Obtain pixel coordinates of an image

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, pixel

I'm working with a tiff image in arcgis projected in UTM 33N and I need to obtain pixel coordinates of a specific point in the image with known metric coords (UTM 33N). How can I get them?

Comment: You can use lower corner coordinates and cell size to obtain row and column. Or you can do it mechanically by sampling rasters OF ROWMAP and COLMAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be two ways to get your coordinates.

The first one is to use Identify Button. You can find it under the Toolbar -> Tools.
[image]

Now Click on the Pixel, where you want to know the coordinates. Now a window opens and you can see the coordinates behind location. But this coordinates are not really exact.
[image]

The second way is to convers the raster into a point feature class. You can do it through your ArcToolbox -> Conversion Tools -> From Raster -> Raster to Point.

[image]

After ths click with identify on the point you want the location from.

I hope this will work for you.